# Как дать описание репозиторию на github?

Tags: github, gitlab

У меня есть репозиторий с файлами, я хочу описать что он из себя представляет, как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62767178/4827341 но при чём тут gitlab?

Comment: в файле README.md. Если вы хотите сделать описание для каких-нибудь пакетных менеджеров, то тут все зависит от языка.